# Stack manipulation in .net

Tags: c#, memory, stack

I would like to understand deeply how the stack of the thread is maintained by the CLR.
If we create a value-based var1 CLR placed this struct at the top of the stack directly and then some other objects can be added to the top of the stack.

So the question is how manipulation with var1 has happened. If we override this variable with a new value CRL should go from the top of the stack (a reference to the stack top should be saved in some cache) and update that object with a new one. So this operation theoretically should be faster if this variable at the top of the stack. Differences should be really small but it interesting how it is maintained.

```
int var1 = 10;
var1 += 30;//should be theoretically faster because CLR shouldn't go deeper into the stack to replace value
int var2 = 20;
//other variables

-----------------

int var1 = 10;
int var2 = 20;
//other variables
var1 += 30;//should be theoretically slower because CLR should go deeper into the stack to replace value
```

Is my assumption correct or I miss some details?

Comment: Your assumption that the variables are stored on the stack is not even a true assumption.  That said, [the stack is an implementation detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one) to begin with that's rarely useful to consider.  Of course, if you want to know if there is a performance difference between your two snippets then *measure behavior of those two snippets* for yourself and see if there is a difference that is material to your application.

Comment: @Servy, it is also can have a semantic meaning, regardless of implementation.  It has to do with the life cycle and scope of the variable.

Comment: @JoelFan Understanding the scope and lifetime of these variables has nothing to do with "the stack".  In fact, there is no need or benefit to using the term "stack" in defining the scope or lifetime of these variables.  Understanding their scope and lifetime is useful and important to most any program, understanding where the memory for these variables is allocated on the physical machine, not so much.

Comment: "and then some other objects can be added to the top of the stack." - objects *never* go on the stack (in the current implementation, this being an implementation detail), so... no?

Comment: @Servy But it is important when this part of the memory for "Stack" goes to some CPU cache that speeds up the accessing of these addresses. So not sure why Jit should decide to allocate everything in the same part of memory ("Heap") and not take advantage of some caching strategy.

Comment: @Oleksandr What are you talking about?  *Any* memory can be cached by the CPU.  From the hardware's perspective, the heap, stack, and everything else is just "memory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance difference in accessing different parts of the stack.  There is no pushing or popping involved in changing values.  The memory location is accessed directly, even if it is located on the stack.  The stack is just memory, like any other.  A variable is associated with a memory address and that memory address is used to read or write the value.

Comment: "There is no performance difference in accessing different parts of the stack." - oh, there can be - when CPU cache comes into play etc; that shouldn't be the case for the code in the question, though, not least because I'd expect the locals to be enregistered

Comment: So CPU is not using this part of memory as "Stack" and just directly takes values based on the memory address, but variables that are stored in this part of memory are still sequential that can help with removing variables from the top of the stack after returning from the method, right?

Comment: @Oleksandr, as I said, "stack" is not special in any way in terms of memory addressing.  It is just another part of memory.  All memory is addressed in the same way.  Every byte has an address that can be accessed directly.